# NGINX reverse proxy HTTP to HTTPS server issue

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing issue with reverse proxy configured using nginx

The curl is showing that the request is reaching the endpoint and this last send the response and it stuck on nginx.

- About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (#0)
- Trying 127.0.0.1...
- Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)

> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml
> SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/AOI
> Content-Length: 1707
> Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
^C
[root@venom conf.d]#

Below my configuration

server {

```
    listen       80 ;
    server_name  80_proxy;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_body_buffer_size 16k; 
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    server_tokens off;
    error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
    proxy_set_header        Host    $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; SameSite=Lax; Max-Age=172800";
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    client_body_timeout     5;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_buffering off;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; always';
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';";
location / {
            proxy_send_timeout      2100;
            proxy_read_timeout      2100;
            client_max_body_size    10M;
            proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.crt;
           proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/cert.key;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/ssl/cert_ca.crt;
            proxy_ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            proxy_ssl_verify on;
            proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
            proxy_pass https://10.34.22.33:801;
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is on NGINX? The error may indicate that the post data is not sent to the server. Can you share the curl command?

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml"  http://127.0.0.1:902  --verbose
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 902 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 902 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:902
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml
>

I'm using the port 902 now

Comment: So you should have some --data parameter to send the post, but I cannot see that part on your curl...

Comment: Hello @KemalKaplan,
I tried with apache and it worked, the issue with nginx is i'm waiting for a status like 200, 403 in order to continue,
If i do the same curl with apache i got error 403 not forbidden (expected) but with nginx nothing happen after the accept 100.
Best Regards
Thanks